# Python 2.7 "\u043a\u0441" into normal string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've got the `unicode(u'test')` string in python 2.7 with `# coding=utf8` at the top of script.
So if i do print it's fine, but if put it in list for example or pass to sqlite3 query, it goes like this `\u043a\u0441` and i exactly can't transform this into normal string.

I've tried to do `encode()` and `decode()` and many other things, nothing is works.

Thanks.

Comment: What you mean by  *it goes **like** this \u043a\u0441* what is it exactly? also print will decode your unicode with `utf8` decoding but it saved it as unicode in data structure and data base. and there it doesn't make any difference since when you want to read your data you can decode it

Comment: I mean i need to create normal str, instead of this trap(\u043a\u0441)

Comment: Please show all the relevant code or we cannot help you.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7VSP0VCF

Comment: There is a trouble that unicode string created with `u'str'` textouts normal string, but string return by `str.translate` textouts something like \u043a\u0441 and its not usable ...

Answer (score 0):

Import the `smart_str` method and then encode to a byte string calling `smart_str(u'\u043a\u0441')`

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str # import smart_str method to convert unicode
```

Comment: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: If it means something, im using Django 1.3 and Python 2.7

Comment: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Not works ... http://pastebin.com/mgDgWQvp   'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: There is a trouble that unicode string created with u'str' textouts normal string, but string return by str.translate textouts something like \u043a\u0441 and its not usable ...